# Reflection and interfaces

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class that indirectly implements an interface (its superclass or super-duper class implements can implement ) and I want to know wheather a class implements an interface or not.

In coding terms :

```
      import java.lang.reflect.Type;

        class My implements MyName{

        }

        public class Tset extends My implements yourName{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Class[] allClassAndInterfaces = Tset.class.getInterfaces();
    //but allClassAndInterfaces is not giving me the MyName Interface 
    //although it gives me YourName Interface
System.out.println(ArrayUtils.toString(lits));
        }
}
```

Comment: Basically, I want to get all the direct and indirect interfaces implemented by a class , and class.getInterfaces() is unable to do that.

Comment: Is there not any direct api...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specific method in the Class class called isAssignableFrom which does what you want. In your case, this should return true:

```
 MyName.class.isAssignableFrom(My.class);
```

Comment: Can I get the list of all implemented Interfaces as well ....is tere any such method

Comment: @Chandan: for that one you do need to follow the class hierarchy (use Class.getSuperclass and Class.getInterfaces).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `instanceof` to check whether an (instance of a) class implements an interface or not.

Edit:

```
interface X { }

class A implements X { }

System.out.println(new A() instanceof X);  // <---- prints true
```

Comment: No, I have a class litrel and it is not in the heirarchy of the Interface I want to check out... for instaceof ...heirarchy is needed

Comment: Ok, I thought you have an instance.